# Testing async methods using Mocha, Chai, node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a very simple code structure like this

### TestWorks.ts

```
const axios = require('axios');

export class TestWorks{

    async getUsersList(param1:TestModel, userDetail:any){

    console.log("BEGIN -- ... ");
```

And then this is my test class

### MyTest.ts

```
const testworks = require("../src/interfaces/TestService/TestWorks");

it('Get Users', async () => {
    var x = await testworks.getUsersList({}, {});
    expect(x).to.be.an("object");
});
```

but I am seeing the following error, unable to figure out what the issue could be. The paths are definitely right, not an issue with the file paths of where the files are

```
Get Users:
     TypeError: testworks.getUsersList is not a function
     at C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\xxxxx\test\test-server.test.ts:53:28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testworks` refers to the module (or whatever TypeScript exports) because you use `require()`. You should use `import` for TypeScript modules.

```
import { TestWorks } from '../src/interfaces/TestService/TestWorks';
```